# why removing key from hash ,removes it also from another hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, key

why removing key from hash ,removes it also from the other hash?

```
msg = { key1: "XXX",key2: 'xxx' }
send_msg(msg)
send_msg(msg)

def send_message(msg)
  p msg
  msg.delete(:key1)
end
```

The output:

```
=> { key1: "XXX",key2: 'xxx' }
=> { key2: 'xxx' }
```

Also:

```
 irb(main):023:0> a = { key1: "XXX",key2: 'xxx' }
    => {:key1=>"XXX", :key2=>"xxx"}
    irb(main):024:0> b=a
    => {:key1=>"XXX", :key2=>"xxx"}
    irb(main):025:0> a.delete(:key1)
    => "XXX"
    irb(main):026:0> a
    => {:key2=>"xxx"}
    irb(main):027:0> b
    => {:key2=>"xxx"}
```

Is it a reference?

Comment: yes it is a reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `#delete` mutates the original `msg` hash. If you want `msg` to stay intact, pass its *duplicate* to `send_msg`:

```
msg = { key1: "XXX",key2: 'xxx' }
send_msg(msg.dup)
send_msg(msg.dup)

def send_message(msg)
  p msg
  msg.delete(:key1)
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea about the `dup` option.